# Value of variable in matlab

Tags: matlab

How can i use this recipe for delete row of matrix?

```
A= [1 2 3 4;5 6 7 8;9 0 1 2;3 4 5 6]

for delete row:
B = A(2,:) = []
```

I need to delete row and putting up to **B**.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. What is preventing you from doing `b=A(2,:); A(2,:)=[]` ? Also, what do you mean by "for delete row" ? Please specify the exact desired behaviour. I think taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve would be useful for your future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a way for delete row of A without change A:

```
A = [1 2 3 4;5 6 7 8;9 0 1 2;3 4 5 6]
B = A;
B(2,:) = [];

Result: B = [1 2 3 4;9 0 1 2;3 4 5 6]
```